Why should I divide token into two things, accessToken and refreshToken?
These days, I'm making login process. I made up my mind to use jwtToken. Here's the thing. I made two token, accessToken and refreshToken. but my coworker said that "why you made two tokens. you just made one token and put two tokens in the token. which means, one token manage accessToken and refreshToken. I've never thougt that why people use accessToken and refreshToken individualy. Is there any reason? Is it better that I make one token to manage two token??
I'd like to know token more.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Hi Aiden, welcome to StackOverflow. Important details are missing from your question, starting with the authentication protocol you are using and what do you mean by "put two tokens in the token". If your question is about OIDC, you might find your answer here.
